# Porting Inline GASM to x64 MASM Access Violation Issue

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86-64, masm

I am currently porting some code to MS Windows x64 from the https://github.com/mono project which was written for GCC Linux and I am having some challenges.

Currently I am unsure if my translation from x64 AT&T inline ASM to x64 MASM is correct. It compiles fine but my test case fails as `memcpy` throws exceptions/memory access violations after my ASM function executes. **Is my translation correct?**

One of the things I was really challenged by was the fact that `rip` is not accessible in Windows x64 MASM? I really don't know how to translate those remaining lines of the AT&T syntax (see below). But I gave it a best try. **Did I handle the lack of `rip` access correctly?**

**If my work is correct then why is `memcpy` failing?**

Here is the related C++:

```
void mono_context_get_current(MonoContext cnt); //declare the ASM func

//Pass the static struct pointer to the ASM function mono_context_get_current
//The purpose here is to clobber it
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define MONO_CONTEXT_GET_CURRENT(ctx) do { \
    mono_context_get_current(ctx);  \
    } while (0)
#endif

static MonoContext cur_thread_ctx = {0};

MONO_CONTEXT_GET_CURRENT (cur_thread_ctx);
memcpy (&info->ctx, &cur_thread_ctx, sizeof (MonoContext)); //memcpy throws Exception.
```

Here is the current ASM function.

```
mono_context_get_current PROTO
.code
mono_context_get_current PROC
mov rax, rcx ;Assume that rcx contains the pointer being passed
mov [rax+00h], rax
mov [rax+08h], rbx
mov [rax+10h], rcx
mov [rax+18h], rdx ;purpose is to offset from my understanding of the GCC assembly
mov [rax+20h], rbp
mov [rax+28h], rsp
mov [rax+30h], rsi
mov [rax+38h], rdi
mov [rax+40h], r8
mov [rax+48h], r9
mov [rax+50h], r10
mov [rax+58h], r11
mov [rax+60h], r12
mov [rax+68h], r13
mov [rax+70h], r14
mov [rax+78h], r15
call $ + 5
mov rdx, [rax+80h]
pop rdx
mono_context_get_current ENDP
END
```

To my understanding the **`rcx`** register should contain the struct pointer and that I should be using `rdx` to `pop`.

As I mentioned I have GCC ASM for non-Win64 platforms which appears to work on those platforms. This is what that code looks like:

```
#define MONO_CONTEXT_GET_CURRENT(ctx)        \
        __asm__ __volatile__(        \
                "movq $0x0, 0x00(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rbx, 0x08(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rcx, 0x10(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rdx, 0x18(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rbp, 0x20(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rsp, 0x28(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rsi, 0x30(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%rdi, 0x38(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r8, 0x40(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r9, 0x48(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r10, 0x50(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r11, 0x58(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r12, 0x60(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r13, 0x68(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r14, 0x70(%0)\n"        \
                "movq %%r15, 0x78(%0)\n"        \
                "leaq (%%rip), %%rdx\n"        \
                "movq %%rdx, 0x80(%0)\n"        \
                :         \
                : "a" (&(ctx))        \
                : "rdx", "memory")
```

Thanks for any help you may be able to offer! I'll be the first to admit my assembly is pretty rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You can let gcc create the asm file for you (gcc can produce MASM syntax as well):

```
gcc -S -masm=intel myfile.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing between the two versions there appears to be some discrepancy:

```
movq $0x0, 0x00(%0)
```

It doesn't look like `rax` is being saved but instead that memory slot is zero'ed out.

```
leaq (%%rip), %%rdx
```

You should be able to translate that into intel synatx:

```
lea rdx, [rip]
```

which is valid if you're using 64-bit relative addressing mode.

And this line is incorrectly translated from att:

```
call $ + 5
mov rdx, [rax+80h] ; looks reversed
pop rdx
```

Here's how I've translated the original gas syntax above:

```
mov qword ptr [rcx], 0
mov [rcx + 0x08], rbx
mov [rcx + 0x10], rax 
mov [rcx + 0x18], rdx 
mov [rcx + 0x20], rbp 
mov [rcx + 0x28], rsp 
mov [rcx + 0x30], rsi 
mov [rcx + 0x38], rdi 
mov [rcx + 0x40], r8
mov [rcx + 0x48], r9
mov [rcx + 0x50], r10
mov [rcx + 0x58], r11
mov [rcx + 0x60], r12
mov [rcx + 0x68], r13
mov [rcx + 0x70], r14
mov [rcx + 0x78], r15
lea rdx, [rip]
mov [rcx + 0x80], rdx
mov rdx, [rcx + 0x18]  ; restore old rdx since it's on clobber list
```

Note that I switched `rcx` around with `rax` just to save an extra `mov`. So `rax` gets saved in place of `rcx` in the gas syntax. You might need to modify this depending on your invariants.

If it still crashes I'd advise stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still not sure how to get around the relative addressing mode issue. As mentioned in the original question I am using MS VS 2010 and ml64 does not want to compile [rip]. Error states "error A2006: undefined symbol : rip". Is there a switch or something to enable rip usage? I had a look here on MSDN and it appears possible? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx